# Using ServiceClient.GetFeedbackReceiver() from Azure IoT SDK to get ACK messages

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-webjobs, windowsiot, azure-iot-hub

I'm looking for a good practice for using `ServiceClient.GetFeedbackReceiver()` to receive acknowledges from devices with Azure IoT SDK.

I have two instances of `IEventProcessor` that handle messages from IoT HUB - one for cold path another for hot path. 
Each EventProcessor may send a message to the device if more data is required.

I need to process ACK from the device to which I sent a message. So I have a "stub code" like this:

```
        var sc = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        var fr = sc.GetFeedbackReceiver();

        while (true)
        {
            var feedbackBatch = await fr.ReceiveAsync();
            if (feedbackBatch == null) continue;

            var myName = GetType().Name;
            Console.WriteLine(myName +": ack list: {0}", string.Join(", ", feedbackBatch.Records.Select(f => f.StatusCode + " for " + f.OriginalMessageId + ";")));

            await fr.CompleteAsync(feedbackBatch);
        }
```

The problem is:

- when I run this code in both EventProcessors (hot and cold) it's complitely random in which I get the feedback-response (ack)!
- both EventProcessors are separated, so I can't just pass received ACK from one to another;

What I need:

- I need the ACK to get back to the EventProcessor the message originated
- or other common, good practice, canonical solution to solve the problem;

Answer (score 2):

No one has posted a better answer, so I will share with my solution.

**Disclaimer: I still don't know whether it's a best possible solution.**

I created a third (new, separate) Event Processor (`IEventProcessor`), **always run as a one instance**, that handles all ACK feedbacks from all devices.

So overall solution is based on three event processors (two receive normal messages for cold and hot path, and the third one for ACKs). All of them (besides specific logic) translate received messages into domain events and put into Event Hub. Further components in my system watch this Hub and handle domain logic.

Remarks:

- It's important to run only one instance of Feedback Receiver (`ServiceClient.GetFeedbackReceiver()` + `ReceiveAsync`) for one IoT Hub. This guarantees that all ACKs will be received deterministic manner.